# Switching scene and its view controller

Tags: sprite-kit

I am switching from one SKScene to another one using transition (this is code in scene.m):

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    SKSpriteNode *logo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"logo"];
    logo.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:logo];
    SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
    [self runAction:pause completion:^{
        MainMenuScene *mainMenu = [[MainMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *fade = [SKTransition  fadeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] duration:2];
        [self.view presentScene:mainMenu transition:fade];
    }];

}
return self;
}
```

In my view controller i have this code :

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;    
    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [LogoScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

But I want for my new scene (MainMenuScene) to set its own view controller. I really don't
 know, how to achieve change of view controllers, when using transition. Can someone show me appropriate piece of code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's called *View*Controller for a reason. You aren't switching the view, so you ought to keep using the same view controller. Scene-specific code goes into the scene instance. You can access the view controller from the scene via self.view.window.rootViewController (from the top of my head, may not be correct).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D You are right, but I wouldn't advise to access ViewController from `SKScene` directly, as this breaks MVC pattern.

Comment: True, though Sprite Kit doesn't have a delegate callback mechanism to the view controller like Cocoa has.